# Can I make device which receives all Sun ligth and changes it in electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, radiation

Is possible to make a device which recives all surround emg radiation in the same time? I'm not thinking about a radio. Rather something very silmilar but able recive all emg radiation in same time.

Comment: I don't know, can you? Anyway, only visible light is interesting for conversion to electricity as it has the highest energy density.

Comment: Like a Dyson sphere?

Answer (score 2):

You would not be able to do better than the limiting thermodynamic efficiency of $1-Tc/Th$, where $Tc$ is the temperature of the microwave background radiation (2.7K) and $Th$ is the temperature of the Sun (6000K), so you'll never do better than 99.96%. 
Engineering-wise it would be impossible to get anything close to this, but a parabolic mirror focusing sunlight on the hot end of a heat engine and a shadowed radiator on the cold end might get a substantial portion.